# Change text properties conditionally?

Tags: text-properties

**Q:** how do I change text properties conditional on other properties?

I have text between region `beg` and `end`.  Each character has
text properties.  I know I can change those text properties in an
unconditional way with something like:

```
(add-text-properties beg end '(some-property t))
```

*How can I change the text properties of characters conditional on their existing properties?*

Here's an example.  Each character in the region has two text
properties, `prop1` and `prop2`, that take on `t` or `nil`
values.  I want to set the value of `prop1` to `t` for only those
characters whose `prop2` value is `t`.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the text using `next-property-change`. At each position, you can check the if `prop2` is set, and if it has the value `t`. If so, set `prop1` to `t`.

Of course, the problem is *when* to do this. If it's fine to do this once, you can simply do this once when your application is started. However, if you want to do this whenever the text is updated (and font-lock is used), you can do this as a side effect in a font-lock rule. In this case, `prop1` must be included in `font-lock-extra-managed-props`.